# I'm trying to use Elasticsearch for finding the overlap of two tag sets

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Given a person with a number of tags and a book with a number of tags, I want to find the best book for that person.

The problem that I'm having with elasticsearch is that with the scoring mechanisms, it looks like a book with one tag takes precedence over a book with many tags.

```
book1.tags = ('good','short')
book2.tags = ('good', 'sci-fi', 'long')
```

and i search with 'good' as my search tag, I'll get a higher score for book1.
likewise, a search for 'good', 'short', 'sci-fi' will also give book 1 (where I might expect them to be equal). It's worse if I have another book with just the 'good' tag.

Is there some way I can add these fields so they are scored as a count? I've been reading all day about TF/DF etc. I basically just want TF.

Is there a good way to do this in Elasticsearch? It seems like such a basic case - ie overlapping two tag fields.

Here is the search I'm running:

```
{'query': {'match': {'tags': 'good'}}}
```

Comment: try disabling [norms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#norms)  on tags field

Comment: Can you post the query you tried?

Comment: I tried disabling norms and according to the warning in the docs, i'm not sure I'll see the difference. I'm also not entirely sure I disabled them correctly. I'm using django-elasticsearch to create my documents. I'm going to be sorting this out today, so I'll report back.

Comment: Turning off norms definitely seemed to help. My attempts at setting the mapping with through the python library weren't working. When I did it manually, now I'm getting much more what I'd want.